# appending a class reference on global variable

Tags: python

I found this code code snippet describe an operation done on the variable `_default_graph` which is being defined as `global` in  `class Graph()` , what i am really missing here is how the operation `_default_graph.placeholders.append(self)` is executed . the attribute `placeholders` is not defined anywhere .

i would like to understand the logic behind this operation and what is called to be familiar with

```
class Placeholder:
    """
    A placeholder is a node that needs to be provided a value for computing the output in the Graph.
    """

    def __init__(self):

        self.output_nodes = []

        _default_graph.placeholders.append(self)


class Graph():


    def __init__(self):

        self.operations = []
        self.placeholders = []
        self.variables = []

    def set_as_default(self):
        """
        Sets this Graph instance as the Global Default Graph
        """
        global _default_graph
        _default_graph = self
```

Comment: um, in `Graph.__init__` you have `self.placeholders = []`.... but yeah, this seems like not the best idea.

Comment: so in  `Graph.set_as_default` this operation   `_default_graph = self` is done to make the `_default_graph` contains `placeholders ` ,   `variables`  and `operations` . i am getting this right or missing something

Comment: What is the best practice do you suggest to mimic the same operation

Comment: Not relying on global state is generally considered best practice, is what I meant. That is, *relying on mutable global state* is what seems like not the best idea. Indeed, the whole *point* of OOP is to avoid mutable, global state, through encapsulation. So yeah, I would say this is just poorly designed code. It's unnecessarily hard to reason about precisely because it relies on mutable global state.

Comment: And no, `_default_graph = self` simply assigns `self` to the *global variable* `_default_graph`. The attributes of your `Graph` object are set during initialization, in the `__init__` method.